# What is the volume of a 4-ball in Minkowski Space?

Tags: differential-geometry, volume

I know the volume of a 4-ball in Euclidean space, but I’m not sure if it would be calculated differently in Minkowski space. Could anybody tell me what the equation for the volume of a 4-ball in Minkowski space is?

Answer (score 2):

I would assume it would be infinite. Since the equation would be $x^2+y^2+z^2-t^2 < \pm r^2$. Which is a some kind of hyperboloid.